# Pass a whole table built with datasetvariables to a Lua function

Tags: context, lua

I am using `ConTeXt` to mark my pupils in a semi-automated way. My comments and grades are stored in dataset variable, as in the MWE below. I am trying to sum automatically points using a `Lua` function inspired by `Lua` wiki. Unfortunately, I do not know how to pass a whole table defined with `\setdataset` to a `Lua` macro.

```
\startluacode
   userdata = userdata or {}
   -- http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleStats
   function userdata.somme(n)
   local sum=0
   -- loop sur key=value d’une table
   for k,v in pairs(t) do
      -- si c’est un nombre, on ajoute à la somme
      if type(v) == 'number' then
         sum=sum+v
      end
   end
   return sum
end
\stopluacode

%how to declare a whole list?
\def\Total#1{userdata.somme(#1)}

\setdataset [Exercice] [Astérix]
   [introduction={Nice try},
    PointsIntro={1},
    conclusion={where is it?},
    PointsConclusion={0},
    Bonus={did you take your magic potion?},
    PointsBonus={},
   ]

\setdataset [Exercice] [Obélix]
   [introduction={too big},
    PointsIntro={1},
    conclusion={don't hurt me!},
    PointsConclusion={0},
    Bonus={you didn't need any magic potion},
    PointsBonus={1},
   ]

\starttext

\Total{Astérix}

\Total{Obélix}
\stoptext
```

`\datasetvariable` returns only one variable, not a whole table, and I am a bit lost with the data structure from the `*tuc` file. How can I declare my Total function to pass all `Asterix` keys and values (that is Astérix's table) as a variable?

I expect `\Total{Astérix}` to return 1 and `\Total{Obélix}` to return 2.

I suspect it might be easier to do the whole thing in `Lua`, but I am not yet able to do it.

Comment: You can get the all entries as a Lua table with `job.datasets.getdata("Exercice","Astérix")` and a single entry as a string with `job.datasets.getdata("Exercice","Astérix","PointsIntro")`.

Comment: That sounds great, by I get an error if I tune my macro like this `\def\Total#1{\ctxlua{userdata.somme(job.datasets.getdata("Exercice",#1))}}`. Any idea why?

Comment: You have to pass the name of the entry as string (`"#1"`) and the names of the variables in your Lua function don't match (`userdata.somme(n)` vs. `pairs(t)`). Another problem is your number check which doesn't work because everything (even the score values) is stored as a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the debugging. How can I store the score value as number? Without the braces? Sadly I was convinced there were numbers…

Comment: You can't change the way how values are stored but you can convert the stored to a number with the `tonumber` function. You can also drop the check when you grab only the values from the `PointsIntro` and `PointsBonus` fields.

Comment: The trouble is that in my sheet, I have 30 keys, 15 of them being numbers (and some of them being nils). Does turning real strings and nil to numbers make sense? Looks like grabing those 15 values should be easier (although ugly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my attempts to use `dataset` failed. Thanks to @Wolfgang Schuster, I understood this is a format issue, that playing with `tonumber`didn't solve. A working — and shorter — solution, is to store those tables directly in lua. For the records and those who are lua newbies, as I am, strings are within quotemarks, numbers aren't.

```
\startluacode
   userdata = userdata or {}
   -- http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleStats
   function userdata.somme(t)
   local sum=0
   -- loop on table key=value
   for k,v in pairs(t) do
      -- if it is a number, then sumed
      if type(v) == 'number' then
         sum=sum+v
      end
   end
   return sum
end

Astérix = {
    introduction="Nice try",
    PointsIntro=2,
    conclusion="where is it?",
    PointsConclusion=0,
    Bonus="did you take your magic potion?",
    PointsBonus=0,
}

Obélix = {
    introduction="too big",
    PointsIntro=1,
    conclusion="don't hurt me!",
    PointsConclusion=2,
    Bonus="you didn't need any magic potion",
    PointsBonus=0,
}
\stopluacode


\starttext

Astérix: \ctxlua{context(userdata.somme(Astérix))}

Obélix: \ctxlua{context(userdata.somme(Obélix))}
\stoptext
```